# Is this an on-topic Question and a valid Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion

Related Question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/58214/12615

The background and motivation are exposed in the Q.
But for further clarification: 5G Blacklist is an HTAccess tool that acts as a Firewall to any platform operating in Apache (in my limited understanding).

Having it installed, I found specific Directives that are incompatible with WordPress.

Is WordPress StackExchange a valid venue to catalog such incompatibilities?

**[edit]**
Or better yet, can the related Q be modified/adapted to be fit?
(as it increasingly seems not to be...)

**[edit 2]**
Copy of the original Q, which self-destructed before being shut-down :)

> The intention of this Question is to catalog the directives of the
>   [Perishable Press 5G Blacklist](http://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2012) that may break or provoke
>   malfunctions in WordPress core and plugins.
>
> > #### What it does
> >
> > The 5G Blacklist is a simple, flexible blacklist that checks all URI
> >     requests against a series of carefully constructed HTAccess
> >     directives. This happens quietly behind the scenes at the server
> >     level, saving resources for stuff like PHP and MySQL for all blocked
> >     requests.
> >
> > #### How it works
> >
> > Blacklists can block just about any part of a request: IP, user agent,
> >     request string, query string, referrer, and everything in between. But
> >     IP addresses change constantly, and user agents and referrers are
> >     easily spoofed. As discussed, request strings yield the best results:
> >     greater protection with fewer false positives.
> >
> > **The 5G works beautifully with WordPress**<sup>1</sup>, and should help any site
> >     conserve bandwidth and server resources while protecting against
> >     malicious activity.
>
> <sup>1 Editor note: *my emphasis*</sup>
>
> Reports are being made in the page comments, but, IMHO, that's not the
>   best venue to search and track incompatibilities that such a nice tool
>   may have with WordPress, as this Stack is.

Comment: It will be _too localized_ the moment Jeff presents the next list.

Comment: Well, it will self-destruct in 60 seconds :) . . . . I'm making a copy here for the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a fitting use of the site to me. It's a little too vague what is being accomplished.

- Fixing the list? Would be better as bug report to original developer.
- Enumerating problems with it? Enumerating badness is simply not productive.

Comment: I agree. Doesn't seem a good fit here, even as a wiki ...

Comment: I understand that: 1) those are not *problems* but Htaccess Directives *incompatibilities* with WP. 2) in a list of *goodness* (that protect any site, WP included), I'd like to record the ones that conflict with WP.

Comment: Just for the record: have you checked what 5G Blacklist is about? . . . . Also, added another question to the Q, thanks for the input!